# ios alarm functionality limited?

Tags: android, ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, alarm

I have an app which is on Android and iOS.  I have added a local notification to fire every 24 hours at a time specified by the user of the app.  In Android, the local notification functionality is exactly what I need, but in iOS it seems to lack the functionality I need, unless maybe I am missing something...

Lets say the user sets the time the notification is to fire to 11:00am.  In Android, at 11AM, it will wake up the app, go to the broadcase receiver and I am able to run code in a method that calls out to an API to fetch the latest data.  Once it gets the data, it posts the notification to the user.

In iOS, it seems the data being posted to the user has to be pre-scheduled.  So I have to create the notification message during scheduling of the notification.  What I need is to be able to do something more like the above example.

So the problem is that at the time of when the notification is scheduled to fire, I need to check for fresh data, not the day before...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same functionality doesn't exactly exist on iOS.

You can setup a local notifications using the functionality of a `UILocalNotification` object. With this you can set `fireDate`, etc. which is sort of like a push notification without a server. You can send a message, add a badge on the app icon, play a sound, etc.

Now the issue is that the app doesn't get launched by the OS. The app simply registers a notification in the OS, which is then handled at the `fireDate` time. This means you won't be able to have a chance to check for data and verify whether to continue with the notification, etc.

[UILocalNotification Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes, I have all of the above working.  But what you said makes sense, it doesnt actually get launched by the OS, more like the OS handles deliverying the notification.  That is the problem for me, but I will just have to live with it.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The OS is just the messenger, when the user then opens the app with the notification your app will launch and you can handle the local notification in the app delegate method and then do your networking at that point.